# Trying to Connect Vertica DB with Weblogic 10.3

Tags: jdbc, database-connection, weblogic-10.x, vertica

Working on Linux Redhat
I have two below jars
1>vertica-jdbc-5.1.1.jar
2>vertica-jdk5-6.1.1-0.jar

Steps that i followed:
1  copied the jars to `$WL_HOME/server/lib`
2 I set the path of the jars to Linux Path like below
export `WL_HOME=/usr/local/WL_Server10.3/sever`
`PATH= ${WL_HOME}/lib:${PATH}`

3 I modified `${WL_HOME}/common/bin/commEnv.sh`

Added my jars entry like below

```
# set up WebLogic Server's class path
WEBLOGIC_CLASSPATH="${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.
jar${CLASSPATHSEP}${WL_HOME}/server/lib/weblogic_sp.
jar${CLASSPATHSEP}${WL_HOME}/server/lib/weblogic.
jar${CLASSPATHSEP}${FEATURES_DIR}/weblogic.server.modules_13.1.1.0.
jar${CLASSPATHSEP}${WL_HOME}/server/lib/webservices.
jar${CLASSPATHSEP}${ANT_HOME}/lib/ant-all.
jar${CLASSPATHSEP}${ANT_CONTRIB}/lib/ant-contrib.jar
${CLASSPATHSEP}${WL_HOME}/server/lib/vertica-jdbc-5.1.1.jar
${CLASSPATHSEP}${WL_HOME}/server/lib/vertica-jdk5-6.1.1-0.jar"
export WEBLOGIC_CLASSPATH
```

//I also tried the below steps googling,................. Optional Step
4> Modified $`{WL_HOME}/server/lib/jdbcdrivers.xml`

Added required parameter
i didnt get what to fill in the `URLClassPathName` value so i ignored it.

5>I restarted the Weblogic server and logged into the admin console
6> I added new JDBC Data Source

While Testing the Connection i am getting below Error:

```
Message icon - Error An error occurred during activation of changes, please see the log for details.
Message icon - Error weblogic.application.ModuleException:
Message icon - Error weblogic.common.ResourceException: Could not create pool connection. The DBMS driver exception was: [Vertica][JDBC](10100) Connection Refused: (11640) Required Connection Key(s): user; (11480) Optional Connection Key(s): autocommit, connsettings, directbatchinsert, logintimeout, loglevel, lognamespace, logpath, readonly, resultbuffersize, sessionlabel, ssl, threepartnaming, transactionisolation
```

**It would be great if someone can help me with the steps to connect Vertica Database to the Weblogic 10.3**

Answer (score 0):

What connection settings are you providing in:

```
"6> Added new JDBC Data Source
7>Followed the steps"
```

The error says you're missing specificying a user:

```
  [Vertica][JDBC](10100) Connection Refused:
  (11640) Required Connection Key(s): user;
  (11480) Optional Connection Key(s): autocommit, connsettings, directbatchinsert, logintimeout, loglevel, lognamespace, logpath, readonly, resultbuffersize, sessionlabel, ssl, threepartnaming, transactionisolation
```

Comment: I followed basic datasource setup steps asked by Weblogic.  UserName,Password,URL,Schema etc...